# High mysql TIME+

Tags: apache, load, system

I'm new to using/monitoring my apache server.  I noticed that the TIME+ for mysql looks very high (comparatively).  Is this unusual?

```
top - 10:35:33 up 17:52,  2 users,  load average: 0.02, 0.06, 0.08
Tasks:  75 total,   1 running,  74 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1536028k total,  1490624k used,    45404k free,    37376k buffers
Swap:  3145724k total,        0k used,  3145724k free,  1199108k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND           
3039 nobody    20   0  181m  46m 6676 S    0  3.1 405:51.16 mysqld             
6043 nobody    20   0 66092  29m 5808 S    0  2.0   0:08.96 httpd              
6117 nobody    20   0 64996  28m 4948 S    0  1.9   0:01.34 httpd              
6000 nobody    20   0 63992  28m 5812 S    0  1.9   0:04.46 httpd              
6016 nobody    20   0 62684  26m 5900 S    0  1.8   0:06.12 httpd              
6084 nobody    20   0 61212  25m 5684 S    0  1.7   0:01.53 httpd              
6115 nobody    20   0 61108  25m 5644 S    0  1.7   0:00.72 httpd              
6053 nobody    20   0 62112  25m 5824 S    0  1.7   0:07.37 httpd              
6130 nobody    20   0 61136  25m 4940 S    0  1.7   0:00.51 httpd              
6087 nobody    20   0 55912  20m 5676 S    0  1.4   0:01.05 httpd
```

Answer (score 0):

`TIME+` is cumulative since the service started, so that's fine as long as the CPU and MEMORY usage is low, which it seems to be in your case.

A high `TIME+` in this case just means your mysql service hasn't shut down in a while...that's  a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in top - notice that 405:51.16 is much longer than the uptime of  17:52.